Vue 3 Components inside Component
Basically.. I have the code below and I want both components (a-comp and b-comp) to show up on the "main" component (my-component).
My CodePen try: https://codepen.io/azmvth/pen/vYqdojq
const app = Vue.createApp({
    components: {
        'my-component': {
            template: `
            <div>
                <a-comp />
                ↑ A COMPONENT MUST SHOW UP ABOVE<br>
                ↓ B COMPONENT MUST SHOW UP BELOW
                <b-comp />
            </div>`
        },

        'a-comp': {
            template: `
            <div>
                AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            </div>`
        },

        'b-comp': {
            template: `
            <div>
                BBBBBBBBBBBBBB
            </div>`
        }
    }
}).mount('body')


This is feasible. What doesn't work exactly? Have a [repro]?

Sorry.. edited it and provided a link with my code

Another option is to register the components on the app itself: createApp(...).component(...).mount(...). Also note mounting on <body> is bad practice, because Vue replaces the mounting element with the result of your app's render function, so any scripts or events added to body prior to mounting the Vue app will be discarded. Use a div for mounting (e.g: #my-amazing-vue-app).

Oh, appreciated the tip!

To begin with, the main component must have both components A and B in its own
components property
Maybe this will help you.
=> https://codepen.io/Dimitar-Georgiev-the-flexboxer/pen/RwzMrgO

const app = Vue.createApp({
    components: {
        'my-component': {
            template: `
            <div>
                <a-comp />
                ↑ A COMPONENT MUST SHOW UP ABOVE<br>
                ↓ B COMPONENT MUST SHOW UP BELOW
                <b-comp />
            </div>`,
            components: {
                'a-comp': {
                    template: `
                    <div>
                        AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                    </div>`
                },
                'b-comp': {
                    template: `
                    <div>
                        BBBBBBBBBBBBBB
                    </div>`
                }
            }
        },
        
    }
}).mount('body')

Best Regards

Perfect! A huge thanks Sir!
